# Как словить IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, исключения

Есть программа, которая открывает файл, считывает с него текст и дробит на страницы. Эти страницы можно перелистывать вперед-назад с помощью клавиш Enter и Backspace.
Рано или поздно возникнет исключительная ситуация, когда на последней странице книги мы хотим посмотреть следующую(выходим за пределы), или на 1й странице хотим листать на страницу назад. 
"Перелистывающие" методы:

```
public void nextP() {
    //  if (pageNumber == page.size() - 1) {
    //   } else
    pageNumber++;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++)
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
}
public void backP() {
    //    if (pageNumber == 0) {
    //        pageNumber++;
    //    } else {
    pageNumber--;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++)
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
}
```

Здесь я задокументировал "проверку", зачем нам это, если можем перехватить ошибку (я правильно размышляю?).
Блок-слушатель, вызывающий вышеперечисленные методы:

```
try {
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_ENTER) {
                    nextP();
                }
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                    backP();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Выход за пределы книги")
    }
```

И все-равно вылетает IndexOutOfBoundsException.
 Как это правильно сделать так, чтобы эта ошибка не вылетала?

В идеале добиться такого результата, когда находясь на последней странице мы жали Enter(переход на следующую (несуществующую) страницу), а программа абсолютно на это не реагировала(не выводила последнюю страницу повторно) и продолжала показывать ту самую последнюю страничку.

Comment: Вы мыслите неправильно. Дешевле и корректней проверить граничные условия (ваш закомментированный код), чем обрабатывать исключение.

Comment: Спасибо, приму на вооружение. 
Если использовать закомментированый код, то программа будет выводить, к примеру, последнюю страничку повторно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы в такой исключительной ситуации программа не реагировала вообще(находясь на последней страничке жмем Enter и ничего не происходит(ни ошибок, ни обновление странички).

Comment: Видимо надо переосмыслить алгоритм, что бы индекс не выходил за границу массива.

Comment: Ошибка не ловится потому, что вы ловите её при попытке добавить слушателя кнопки, а не в обработке самого нажатия.

Comment: >> Дешевле и корректней проверить граничные условия (ваш закомментированный код), чем обрабатывать исключение

не всегда, иногда лучше перехватить исключение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, просто прерывать работу метода? Раз ничего делать не нужно?

```
public void nextP() {
      if (pageNumber == page.size() - 1) { return ;
       } else
    pageNumber++;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++)
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
}
public void backP() {
        if (pageNumber == 0) {
            return ;
        } else 
    pageNumber--;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++)
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Просто и эффективно. То, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
public void nextP() throws IndexOfBoundsException {
    pageNumber++;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++){
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
    }
}
public void backP() throws IndexOfBoundException {
    pageNumber--;
    for (int i = 0; i < page.get(pageNumber).size(); i++){
        System.out.println(page.get(pageNumber).get(i));
    }

}
```

Переменную pageNumber нужно передавать в методы как параметр, а уменьшать ее в вызывающем коде.
И циклы пишите с фигурными скобками, так легко запутаться, кол-во строк не показатель.

Comment: Не совсем понял Вашу строчку "Переменную pageNumber нужно передавать в методы как параметр".
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
private int pageNumber = 0;
public void nextP() throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{...

Вы это имели ввиду?
Блок try-catch так и оставить?
Ошибка все равно вылетает(

Comment: Да try-catch оставить и если у Вас ошибка которую вы не можете обработать, приводите код класса (а не методы по отдельности) и stackTrace ошибки, а пока разговор ни о чем.

Answer (score 0):

Не там ловите исключение:

```
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_ENTER) {
                          nextP();
                    }
                    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
                           backP();
                    }
               } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                       System.out.println("Выход за пределы книги")
               }
            }
        });
```